# Find local minima in noisy data with exact criteria and without for-loop

Tags: r, vector

I have a timerow and would like to find minima which fulfill specific criteria. Those are that the number of points within the valleys (below the red line) between 2 peaks should exceed a certain value and also the number of points above the red line should exceed a certain value for each peak neighboring the valley. Also the lower of the two peaks should be resolved at a value lower than 50% of its height (meaning that the max(intensity) of the lower of the two peaks should be at least 2 fold the intensity of the lowest intensity within the valley between the two peaks - as calculated below in the code sample). I drew the red line here at a specific height but in reality those unresolved peaks can have any height and can also be seperated by any distance. So what I am doing at the moment is to "scan" with the red line over each point of the time series which is of course very slow and inefficient.

[image]

So here is the for-loop I am using at the moment:

```
detect_double_peaks <- function(pot.doubleP.v, Min.PpP = 10) {

  peak.dt <-
    data.table(
      breakP = NA,
      breakH = NA,
      resolved = NA
    )


  for (point in pot.doubleP.v[pot.doubleP.v > 0 &
                              pot.doubleP.v < 0.8 * max(pot.doubleP.v)]) {
    doublePeak.rle <- S4Vectors::Rle(pot.doubleP.v > point)
    doublePeak.rle.dt <-
      data.table(
        idx = as.numeric(seq.int(length(
          doublePeak.rle@values
        ))),
        values = doublePeak.rle@values,
        lengths = doublePeak.rle@lengths,
        start = start(doublePeak.rle),
        end = end(doublePeak.rle)
      )

    doublePeak.rle.dt_p <-
      doublePeak.rle.dt[values == TRUE & lengths > Min.PpP]

    if (nrow(doublePeak.rle.dt_p) > 1) { 


      for(peak in 1:nrow(doublePeak.rle.dt_p)-1){
        doublePeak.rle.dt_v <- doublePeak.rle.dt[idx > doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak]$idx & idx < doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak + 1]$idx]


        if(sum(doublePeak.rle.dt_v[values == FALSE]$lengths) >= max(max(doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak]$lengths, doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak+1]$lengths) * 0.5, Min.PpP)){


          dp.p_height_h <-
            max(max(pot.doubleP.v[(doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak]$start):(doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak]$end)]),
                max(pot.doubleP.v[(doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak + 1]$start):(doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak + 1]$end)]))# - baseL

          dp.p_height_l <-
            min(max(pot.doubleP.v[(doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak]$start):(doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak]$end)]),
                max(pot.doubleP.v[(doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak + 1]$start):(doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak + 1]$end)]))# - baseL

          breakH <-
            min(pot.doubleP.v[min(doublePeak.rle.dt[idx > doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak]$idx]$start):max(doublePeak.rle.dt[idx < doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak+1]$idx]$end)])# - baseL

          resolved <-
            breakH / dp.p_height_l * 100

          breakP <-
            which.min(pot.doubleP.v[min(doublePeak.rle.dt[idx > doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak]$idx]$start):max(doublePeak.rle.dt[idx < doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak+1]$idx]$end)]) +
            doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak]$end

          peak.dt <- rbind(peak.dt,
                           data.table(breakP = breakP,
                                      breakH = breakH,
                                      resolved = resolved))
        }
      }
    }
    }


  if(nrow(peak.dt) == 1) {return(NULL)} else{
    return(na.omit(unique(peak.dt, by="breakP")))
  }
}
```

Here are some example data:

```
testvector <- c(13126.177734375, 12040.060546875, 10810.6171875, 10325.94140625, 
13492.8359375, 33648.5703125, 14402.603515625, 29920.12890625, 
24316.224609375, 36019.26171875, 34492.4609375, 53799.82421875, 
45988.72265625, 47930.453125, 67438.9140625, 61231.83984375, 
56710.9140625, 62301.6796875, 54844.7578125, 70913.578125, 81028.1640625, 
75234.203125, 59611.05078125, 79240.4375, 52313.3828125, 78758.2734375, 
87918.5859375, 80764.7421875, 108035.5390625, 76263.875, 72401.6796875, 
83167.640625, 76173.96875, 66241.4296875, 68687.4375, 52107.83984375, 
45672.5390625, 51907.33203125, 39967.453125, 58856.90625, 52402.53125, 
36980.3125, 43365.76171875, 40480.75, 39057.96484375, 31622.58984375, 
23830.455078125, 27393.30078125, 30675.208984375, 27327.48046875, 
25150.08984375, 23746.212890625, 9637.625, 19065.58984375, 21367.40625, 
6789.0625, 9892.7490234375, 26820.685546875, 19965.353515625, 
28281.462890625, 25495.0703125, 28808.416015625, 40244.03125, 
35159.421875, 35257.984375, 39971.8046875, 34710.4453125, 60987.73828125, 
50620.06640625, 58757.69140625, 52998.97265625, 55601.96484375, 
69057.9453125, 58486.52734375, 66115.4765625, 80801.7578125, 
77444.6015625, 43545.48828125, 79545.0703125, 50352.484375, 77401.8671875, 
85118.421875, 80521.9296875, 68945.8125, 93098.0234375, 83065.8046875, 
95970.8203125, 74141.8828125, 90298.75, 81251.0234375, 99658.3359375, 
88812.2578125, 81939.4921875, 82632.1015625, 100125.0078125, 
71627.84375, 70560.1484375, 77831.765625, 68122.328125, 79049.140625, 
88000.890625, 64897.4453125, 57333.3046875, 68185.3046875, 67742.3515625, 
58941.85546875, 63184.8671875, 36998.67578125, 45416.58984375, 
31547.3359375, 32141.58203125, 35292.9765625, 30511.861328125, 
25419.716796875, 23901.431640625, 15616.8759765625, 14469.16015625, 
15026.0009765625, 18321.42578125, 15820.861328125, 19532.056640625, 
13230.6240234375, 14586.76953125, 14912.642578125, 8541.5224609375, 
21740.98046875, 19588.986328125, 18603.662109375, 19656.5625, 
10812.94921875, 18379.3359375, 31242.716796875, 25626.0390625, 
42446.71875, 27782.294921875, 38450.703125, 39070.97265625, 52914.375, 
56484.47265625, 47741.88671875, 52397.18359375, 79378.2109375, 
77866.078125, 55902.09765625, 66988.2265625, 63571.01171875, 
66192.53125, 79989.8046875, 57204.59765625, 51172.9921875, 49612.16015625, 
60508.0390625, 69518.09375, 48079.5625, 48691.0390625, 33679.12890625, 
30697.470703125, 31209.359375, 49656.16796875, 32041.912109375, 
13851.48828125, 29316.44921875, 31586.216796875, 45422.19921875, 
24208.515625, 31496.083984375, 26250.646484375, 14318.302734375
)
```

For this vector the minima at 56 and 125 should be returned.

Those should be returned because when scanning with the red line through the points of the vector there is at least one iteration at which there are more than `Min.PpP = 10` consecutive points above the red line on each side of the valley, and with the same red line there are also more than `Min.PpP = 10` points in the valley. The reason why point 4 should not be returned as minima is that no matter where we put the red line the valley will never exceed 3 points (which is lower than `Min.PpP = 10`) and the peak on the left side of that minima would only be 1 point (which is also lower than `Min.PpP = 10`).

I am aware of functions like `pastecs::turnpoints`. However, they do not seem to offer the implementation of criteria as I want to use them. 
So it there any other more efficent way to achive that?

Ps.: 
I have also put another criteria in the example code which says that there should be at least halve as many points in the vally as there are for the peak with the smaller number of points even when Min.PpP is exceeded:

`if(sum(doublePeak.rle.dt_v[values == FALSE]$lengths) >= max(max(doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak]$lengths, doublePeak.rle.dt_p[peak+1]$lengths) * 0.5, Min.PpP))`

However I guess thats not really important for this problem.

Comment: could you explain a bit more the condition to find 56 and 125 ? It is confusing. You need to find local minima ? why is 4 not returned ?

Comment: I edited the questions. Hope that makes it more understandable

Comment: What is the meaning of "resolved" in "...the lower of the two peaks should be resolved at a value lower than 50% of its height..."? Also -- what is the meaning of "height" in that clause?

Comment: it means that the ratio between the the smalles value in the valley and the biggest value of the smaller of the two peaks next to the valley should be lower than 0.5:
`min(valley_intensity) / min(max(neighboring_peak_intensity)) < 0.5`